# Only create logs' directory if logger has file handler

Tags: python, logging

Python's logger library will create the log file if it doesn't exist but not any parent directories.

Our code creates the parent directories regardless of whether the logger is configured to use a [`FileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.FileHandler).

We're now running in a docker, using only console output, and want to avoid creating the directory if there is no file handler installed.

Is there a way to detect this configuration?

Comment: You could inherit from `FileHandler` and create the directories in its `__init__` function.

Comment: How would I cause the logging framework to use my file rather than the built-in `FileHandler`?

Comment: How are you causing the logging framework to use the built-in `FileHandler` now?

Comment: Via it's `fileConfig` and `dictConfig` functions

Comment: `if not logger.handlers: delete_created_dirs()`? Or check if none of the handlers in `logger.handlers` are instances of `FileHandler`.

Comment: You can pass the class of the handler in either format: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details

Comment: @jfaccioni that works, with the drawback of having to create a `logger` instance in our init code just to look at its `handlers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`dictConfig()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details) shows how you can configure handlers of a particular type, and that can be extended to your own handlers.

You could subclass `FileHandler` and override the `emit()` method like this:

```
def emit(self, record):
    dn = os.path.dirname(self.baseFilename)
    if not os.path.exists(dn):
        os.makedirs(dn)
    super().emit(record)
```

and then use this subclass in your logging configuration. However, make sure you instantiate the handler with `delay=True` and, if you override `__init__()` in your custom handler, call the parent class' `__init__()` from there. The `delay=True` doesn't try to open the file until there is an actual need to write to it; that's done by the `FileHandler.emit()` method, and by creating the directory in the overridden method before calling the base class' `emit()` method, you'll only create the directory when it's needed and doesn't already exist.